# How can the Theil-Sen estimator be made to work on larger datasets?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, memory

The Theil-Sen estimator finds the slope and intercept of a line passing through a set of points by calculating the median slope and median intercept of the set of lines passing through all possible distinct point pairs. It is spectacular at fitting a line through data containing outliers.

Here is a reasonably efficient way of calculating this for medium-sized sets of points:

```
slope[data:{{_,_}..}]:=Median[
 Join@@Table[
  (data[[;;-(n+1),2]] - data[[n+1;;,2]]) / (data[[;;-(n+1),1]] - data[[n+1;;,1]]),
  {n,Length[data]-1}
 ]
]
intercept[data:{{_,_}..}]:=Median[
 Join@@Table[
  (data[[;;-(n+1),1]] data[[n+1;;,2]] - data[[n+1;;,1]] data[[;;-(n+1),2]]) /
  (data[[;;-(n+1),1]] - data[[n+1;;,1]]),
  {n,Length[data]-1}
 ]
]
```

However, on a machine with 16 GB of RAM, this runs out of memory when processing somewhere between 20,000 points and 50,000 points. How can the code be made more memory-efficient to operate on bigger datasets?

Here is a way of generating an example value for `data`:

```
sampleData[nPoints_Integer?Positive]:=(
 SeedRandom[0];
 datax = 10 N[Normalize[Range[nPoints],Max]];
 Transpose[{
  datax,
  1 + 0.001 datax + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,0.01],nPoints] +
  datax RandomChoice[{0.01,1-0.01}->{0.02,0},nPoints]
 }]
)
```

Comment: Maybe some useful information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3888036).

Comment: TAOCP offers a collection of extremely efficient methods for such tasks. Truth is: Basic principles of computer sciences cannot be outsmarted by any kind of "standard software".

Comment: Is there some reason not to use a sampling of point pairs, say `n log(n)` or so for `n` points? I think I know of an approach that uses maybe `O(n)` storage but the time complexity would be `n^2 log(n)` and that's quite steep for the size range in question. And fishing through the details for an actual implementation would be not so easy.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, is a random sample guaranteed to give the same answer? One of the main benefits of the technique is its insensitivity to outliers, even if a substantial fraction of the data is composed of outliers. I'd hate to get unlucky and randomly sample only pairs that include the outlier data.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no such guarantee beyond what statistics might indicate (e.g. in terms of variance from "correct" median).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, well as the bounty is nonrefundable and there has been no explosion of interest in this question, I suppose an answer that neatly packages a random sampling method could still win.

Comment: With 20,000 to 50,000 points of real-world data assuming that the functional relationship can be adequately described by a straight line would seem to be more of an issue than not getting the "exact" median slope with a random sample.  Something like quantile regression might be a better approach that does "ignore" extreme values.

Answer (score 7):

As a starting point, here is a compact implementation of Theil-Sen:

```
theilSen[data_?MatrixQ] := Median[With[{df = First[Differences[#]]},
                             {df[[2]], -Det[#]}/df[[1]]] & /@ Subsets[data, {2}]]
```

It is a bit more efficient than the routine in the OP when I tested it on *small* sets of points.

---

In fact, this formulation shows why it may have trouble "when processing somewhere between 20,000 points and 50,000 points." For data of length $n$, you will be generating $\binom{n}{2}$ subsets. $\binom{50\,000}{2}\approx1.25\times 10^9$, and having that many point pairs will indeed give your computer a hard time. Thus, to process that many points, one might consider resorting to [lazy subset generation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86138). But, this presents another problem: updating the median when a slope and intercept are generated. There has been some work (e.g. [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/median/)) on median updating, but I haven't gotten around to fully digesting the literature. I might edit this post later if I figure out a nice implementation of median updating.

Comment: (+1) It is amazing what you packed into a single line of code!

Comment: I was amused at how compact it was, but seeing it break on moderately-sized datasets was a cold shower. ;)

Comment: Works nice. "data" format is $\{\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_2,y_2\},\{x_3,y_3\},\dots,\{x_{n-1},y_{n-1}\},\{x_n,y_n\}\}$ as usual.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ResourceFunction for TheilSenLine. See https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TheilSenLine/.
That may give you a bit of flexibility and is even shorter than the other answer here (which is brilliant BTW), but it bogs down with large $n$. In fact, my kernal quit trying $5\times10^5$ points, presumably the memory allocation was exceeded (I set mine low to avoid obliterating crashes). Trying $10^3$ points took 1.24 s and $10^4$ points took a long time, 93.8 s, see below.

```
dist = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}]; 
pointlist = RandomVariate[dist, 10^3];
AbsoluteTiming[line = ResourceFunction["TheilSenLine"][pointlist]]
Show[ListPlot[pointlist], Plot[line[[1]] x + line[[2]], {x, Min[pointlist[[All, 1]]], Max[pointlist[[All, 2]]]}]]

dist = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}];
pointlist = RandomVariate[dist, 10^4];
AbsoluteTiming[line = ResourceFunction["TheilSenLine"][pointlist]]
Show[ListPlot[pointlist], Plot[line[[1]] x + line[[2]], {x, Min[pointlist[[All, 1]]], Max[pointlist[[All, 2]]]}]][![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As to the question about efficient implementation there are several papers to that effect a few of which are listed on a Cross-validated [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/120718/99274). Unfortunately, I have not been seen Mathematica code for those. Another question, not asked, is how to determine confidence intervals, and one way is to use bootstrap, e.g., see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/406420/99274), but there are faster ways as well.

Comment: Did you ever manage to read the "Author Notes" at the very bottom of the resource function you are linking to?

Comment: @J.M.'slackofA.I. I upvoted your answer before i read about your code. Very nice.

Comment: @J.M.'seventualburnout How about code for the whole enchilada? Would you do that or is it over the top?