# Consecutive generation of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, subset

It is well known that the array of subsets of even small set is very big. This leads to problems with machine memory.
Is there an effective way to generate subsets sequentially?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554)?

Comment: Is this a *Mathematica*-specific question?

Comment: Yes, it's about Mathematica.
The answer is interesting, but unwieldy enough. May be in a new version there is a better way?

Comment: Related: [Alternative to Subsets to generate k-combinations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86138/14303)

Comment: @jkuczm That seems close enough to consider a duplicate.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html) function has a third argument to return only some subsets.  For example,

```
Subsets[set, All, {k1, k2}]
```

returns the `k1`th through the `k2`th subsets.  This allows for easy sequential generation in blocks. Please check the documentation for details.

Comment: Great! I guess to use `Nest` and hope it will work.

Comment: @lesobrod I *assume* this won't use extra memory, but I haven't actually tested ...  you better test this first.

Comment: I assume that NextSubset is implemented carefully enough that it does not  generate the entire set just to find the next element. Be sure to click on the Details in the documentation to understand the usage.

Comment: @Bill You mean `NextSubset` from Combinatorica?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, which was why I included the hint to click on Details.

Comment: @Szabolcs If you could leave a small example in your answer with values ​​would be interesting. At the moment I'm reading on my cell phone and it's not the first time I see this answer when I do a search.