# How to use Table function with two parameters executed when they are not equal?

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I have a list,

```
param2 = {
 {-qlim, -qlim},
 {-qlim, qlim},
 {qlim, -qlim},
 {qlim, qlim}
};
```

and want to get combination of them with,

```
Flatten[Table[{param2[[i]], param2[[j]]}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 2]
```

But this gives me list which includes sets that have item twice. I want to get

```
{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}
```

Comment: What's the value of `qlim`?

Comment: it is a scalar value like 1 or 3

Comment: That's not the answer to my question. I still don't know what do you want to achieve with your code, but the desired output can be obtained with `Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, i + 1, 4}], 1]`.

Comment: Actually ı have written the index inside the list not the actual output. I didn't know that we can use one index inside other. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: See also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86138/121

Comment: "I didn't know that we can use one index inside other." - it pays to read the docs before asking questions. The second example under "Scope" in the docs for `Table[]` shows how you could've done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Subsets[param2, {2}]
```

> {{{-qlim, -qlim}, {-qlim,   qlim}},
>       {{-qlim, -qlim}, {qlim, -qlim}},
>       {{-qlim, -qlim}, {qlim, qlim}},
>       {{-qlim, qlim}, {qlim, -qlim}},
>       {{-qlim, qlim}, {qlim,  qlim}},
>       {{qlim, -qlim}, {qlim, qlim}}}

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted.  What if ı just wanted this point to draw rectangle with these points are corner.

Comment: @freezer, something like `Graphics[{Hue@RandomReal[], Rectangle @@ #}] & /@ (Subsets[
    param2, {2}] /. qlim -> 1)`?

Comment: nope @kglr. I think this is not what I asked. I want to get this list     {{{-3, -3}, {3, -3}}, {{3, -3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, {{-3, 
   3}, {-3, -3}}}    as corners of ractangles automatically? Is this possible?

Comment: @freezer, `Rectangle @@@ {{{-3, -3}, {3, -3}}, {{3, -3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {-3, 
    3}}, {{-3, 3}, {-3, -3}}}` gives `{Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, -3}], Rectangle[{3, -3}, {3, 3}], 
 Rectangle[{3, 3}, {-3, 3}], Rectangle[{-3, 3}, {-3, -3}]}`. Note that some of these are simply lines (degenerate rectangles).

Comment: :) I think I couldn't be clear as I need. I need to get that list from possible values of coordinates. Don't want to write manually.

Comment: @freezer, you mean `Rectangle @@@ Subsets[param2, {2}] /. qlim -> 3`?

Comment: no :D. Forget about rectangle function I want to get a list of points where the corner of rectangles are. Which will generate 4 coordinates out of   +-some value for corners. This is different question than the main question that I asked here.