# Bad linear fit for simple data

Tags: fitting

I have some data :

```
data={{1.01074, 0.964488}, {1.08552, 0.993067}, {1.07907, 
  1.01836}, {1.0477, 1.03695}, {1.07717, 1.07973}, {1.10243, 
  1.08195}, {1.12669, 1.09112}, {1.09405, 1.09319}, {1.10857, 
  1.08445}, {1.18604, 1.08802}, {1.13138, 1.08727}, {1.18706, 
  1.08722}, {1.24118, 1.08473}, {1.27214, 1.08528}, {1.22428, 
  1.08384}, {1.30453, 1.08341}, {1.32046, 1.08277}, {1.32045, 
  1.07894}, {1.34901, 1.08288}, {1.35976, 1.08096}, {1.31244, 
  1.08093}, {1.28729, 1.08611}, {1.25115, 1.08975}, {1.18522, 
  1.09474}, {1.11788, 1.09777}, {1.00822, 0.964488}, {1.0938, 
  0.993067}, {1.10913, 1.01836}, {1.01039, 1.03695}, {1.02588, 
  1.07973}, {1.06003, 1.08195}, {1.06165, 1.09112}, {1.03693, 
  1.09319}, {1.01026, 1.08445}, {1.14019, 1.08802}, {1.03334, 
  1.08727}, {1.08583, 1.08722}, {1.17145, 1.08473}, {1.20567, 
  1.08528}, {1.13422, 1.08384}, {1.20849, 1.08341}, {1.27168, 
  1.08277}, {1.24355, 1.07894}, {1.25894, 1.08288}, {1.30205, 
  1.08096}, {1.18572, 1.08093}, {1.14212, 1.08611}, {1.08297, 
  1.08975}, {0.982202, 1.09474}, {0.861208, 1.09777}, {1.01326, 
  0.964488}, {1.07724, 0.993067}, {1.04902, 1.01836}, {1.08501, 
  1.03695}, {1.12847, 1.07973}, {1.14484, 1.08195}, {1.19174, 
  1.09112}, {1.15116, 1.09319}, {1.20687, 1.08445}, {1.23189, 
  1.08802}, {1.22942, 1.08727}, {1.28829, 1.08722}, {1.31091, 
  1.08473}, {1.33861, 1.08528}, {1.31435, 1.08384}, {1.40056, 
  1.08341}, {1.36924, 1.08277}, {1.39734, 1.07894}, {1.43907, 
  1.08288}, {1.41747, 1.08096}, {1.43915, 1.08093}, {1.43246, 
  1.08611}, {1.41933, 1.08975}, {1.38824, 1.09474}, {1.37454, 
  1.09777}}
```

And I tried to fit them :

```
ab = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[ab, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

But it gives something very weird :

[image]

I don't get what's going on.... Could you help me please ?

Thx

Comment: You can check the other parameters, for example SSE, R-square. It is not good just y eye. Maybe you an make you y a bit large.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you could use [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) to find inliers by consensus. This implementation isn't exactly right but it finds a pretty decent fit:

```
samplesize = 30;
inliers[fit_, points_, d_] :=
 Select[points, Abs[#[[2]] - (fit /. x -> #[[1]])] < d &]
votes = Association[# -> 0 & /@ data];
Do[
  sample = RandomSample[data, samplesize];
  fit = Fit[sample, {1, x}, x];
  Scan[votes[#] += 1 &, inliers[fit, data, 0.05]];
  , 2000];
finalfit = Fit[Keys[TakeLargest[votes, samplesize]], {1, x}, x];
Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[finalfit, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ransac fit]

Answer (score 23):

Use `PlotRange -> All`. Most plot functions tend to throw away points that aren't nicely clustered with the bulk:

```
Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], Plot[ab, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

> [image]

As you can see, there is a number of points that completely mess up the fit.

Comment: Maybe the data are not good. If the data below can be deleted， it would be better.

Comment: Maybe, but you can't just throw away data because it messes up your fit. There needs to be a good motivation for that.

Comment: I mean that the author should check data again. Make sure that the data are OK.  In fact, if you make the range in y direction a bit large, for example from 0 to 2,  the fitting will be better.

Comment: I joined this site just to upvote this answer. And to point to [What are the worst (commonly adopted) ideas/principles in statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/476424/1352), because [one of the answers there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476464/1352) explicitly addresses removing outliers without a good reason.

Answer (score 10):

Use [Quantile Regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]

QRMonUnit[data]⟹
  QRMonQuantileRegressionFit[{1, x}]⟹
  QRMonLeastSquaresFit[{1, x}]⟹
  QRMonPlot;
```

[image]

(And, yes, that is a good example of Quantile Regression's robustness.)

#### Update

Instead of computing with the `QRMon` package utilized above, the computations can be done with the Wolfram Function Repository function [QuantileRegression](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuantileRegression). That function uses B-splines, but if the fitting is made with one knot and interpolation order one then linear function fits are obtained.

```
probs = {0.25, 0.5, 0.75};
qFuncs = ResourceFunction["QuantileRegression"][data, 1, probs, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Simplify[Through[qFuncs[x]]]
Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Gray, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]},
 Plot[Evaluate[Through[qFuncs[x]]], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
   Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, PlotLegends -> probs, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also try [Theil–Sen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) which is less sensitive to outliers. Using the WL implementation from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97657/58370) answer on your data gives slope, intercept of `{0.0037716, 1.07855}`. Plot of your data and a line with that slope, intercept.

[image]