# Fitting a dataset while keeping the risk of overfitting low

Tags: fitting

I have the following dataset:

```
data = {{0, 1351.53}, {3, 1087.17}, {6, 1172.23}, {9, 1231.27}, {15, 1476.93}, {18, 1470.70}, {21, 1326.23}, {24, 316.80}}
```

which looks like

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

I need to fit this dataset with one or two free parameters at most. I usually fist use FindFormula[data] to get a feeling how the fitting function should look like; however, here it doesn't seem to be helpful as I cannot make sense of the result. What are the other approaches to fit this dataset?

**EDIT1**

My first attempt, but it seems that I'm overfitting the data:

```
pp = Fit[data, {1, x^2, x^3}, x]
```

which gives

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[pp, {x, 0, 25}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

Also, the dataset with the corresponding errors:

```
datae = {{0, Around[1351.53, 366.6818830176006]}, {3, Around[1087.17, 336.12935506041913`]}, {6, Around[1172.23, 302.7905271525735]}, {9, Around[1231.27, 257.5652603386826]}, {15, Around[1476.93, 10.45482344821443]}, {18, Around[1470.7, 57.16826042481958]}, {21, Around[1326.23, 175.39855567630354`]}, {24, Around[316.8, 45.14022596310301]}}

ListPlot[datae]
```

[image]

Comment: In order to meaningfully fit a model to a dataset there needs to be some pattern in the data... Can you tell us what process generated the data, and why you expect there to be a pattern?

Comment: @Sara `{1, x^2, x^3}` you're missing an x^1 in there. There is no clear cut answer for how many parameters you should choose. You may want to consider using `FitRegularization->{"LASSO", 1.0}` where `1.0` is up to you. This will try to minimize the L1 norm of the parameters which tries to keep parameters small. Also you could try the RANSAC algorithm [like in my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225990/72682) which gives you a more robust estimation and downplays the effects of outliers. More simply, you could just drop that last point from the data and fit a line.

Comment: @Sara I don't think it is - you should have an $x$ term in there unless you have a very good reason not to suspect an x^1 term in the underlying process this data comes from.

Comment: "I'm still studying the involved mechanisms and I don't know if there is a pattern or not;"  That's a very reasonable statement.  So why not just show the points and the error bars?  Otherwise, (based on the comments here and in the current answer) it appears that you're using the "I'll know it when I see it" decision rule.  A fit can wait until either there's more data or some theoretical model is justified.

Comment: You only have 8 data points and the source of your error values hasn't been explained.  While those errors might be accurately associated with measurement error, that doesn't address any additional lack-of-fit error (especially as the underlying curve is unknown).  And, to repeat:  you only have 8 data points.  One shouldn't expect magic to happen.  And I get that 8 data points might have been very expensive to obtain and that this can be cutting-edge science.  It's simply that there's no statistical method that will fix having only 8 data points.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Manipulate` over the parameters of interest or possible parameters.

Below is given an example with the number of functions in a certain basis. But, of course, other bases or parameters can be programmed and used.

---

```mathematica
Manipulate[
 fFunc = 
  Fit[data, Table[ChebyshevT[i, Rescale[x, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]], {-1, 1}]], {i, 0, n - 1}], x];
 Grid[{{"Plot",
    ListPlot[{data, {#, fFunc /. x -> #} & /@ data[[All, 1]]}, 
     Joined -> {False, True}, PlotLegends -> {"data", "fit"}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
     ImageSize -> Medium]},
   {"Simplfied", Simplify[fFunc]}},
  Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray
  ],
 {{n, 3, "basis size"}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Sara Please run the posted code and use the slider -- you will get better fits. Also, try replacing the Chebysev basis with your own basis of functions. With more data points you will start seeing the overfitting effects.

Comment: Well, I would rather use [Quantile Regression](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuantileRegression/) with B-splines instead of `Fit` with polynomials (with infinite support). (See the section "Properties and Relations" and in link above.)

Comment: "Does this mean that at the end this regression also gives us polynomials?" -- Using B-spline basis we get piecewise polynomials.